# How to pass command-line arguments to vue.config.js?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I’m trying to configure a vue project so that the webpack-dev-server proxies requests for `/data` to one of two hosts, depending on which npm-run command is invoked:

```
npm run serve-foo
npm run serve-bar
```

Here is the configuration:

```
// package.json
{
  scripts: {
    'serve-foo': 'vue-cli-service serve -- http://192.168.7.2',
    'serve-bar': 'vue-cli-service serve -- http://192.168.7.3',
}
```

and

```
// vue.config.js

// prints "node.exe vue-cli-service.js serve -- http://192.168.7.2"
console.log(...process.argv); 

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    // ...
    proxy: {
      '/data': {
        target: process.argv[4]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I run npm run serve-foo the following error occurs. **What am I doing wrong?** Does `vue-cli-service` not support using `--` to pass through arguments?

```
This dependency was not found:

C:\Project\http:\192.168.7.2 in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.5:80/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./http:/192.168.7.2, multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:80 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.5:80/sockjs-node ./http:/192.168.7.2
To install it, you can run: npm install --save C:\Project\http:\192.168.7.2
```

Comment: It's a js problem,you need quote around  process.argv[4], probably not use a space bewteend -- and http, and also remove --

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this via environment variables:

```
// package.json
{
  scripts: {
    'serve-foo': 'export BACKEND_URL=http://192.168.7.2 && vue-cli-service serve',
    'serve-bar': 'export BACKEND_URL=http://192.168.7.3 && vue-cli-service serve',
}
```

and

```
// vue.config.js    
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    // ...
    proxy: {
      '/data': {
        target: process.env.BACKEND_URL
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In case you use windows and receive the error `'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` you need to replace `export` with `set`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ENV because of cross platform concerns, you can parse it out of the `process.argv`.

For example, showing how to capture port from the following command:

`> vite --port 3000`

```
const PORT = process.argv.find((arg) => arg.startsWith('--port='))?.split('=')[1] || 8080;
```